# How can I cure non-normality of residuals in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, residuals, normality-assumption

I am running a logistic regression against the "Default" dataset of [ISLR](https://www.statlearning.com/resources-first-edition).

I am using the [performance](https://github.com/easystats/performance) package in R (available on CRAN) to test the goodness of my model.

MWE:

```
rm(list=ls())
indf <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/suXpddVR")
indf$default <- as.factor(indf$default)
indf$student <- as.factor(indf$student)
mod <- glm(default ~ student+balance+income,
           data=indf,
           family="binomial")
print(summary(mod))

library(performance)
performance::check_model(mod)
```

Diagnostic plot is as follows:
[image]

As you can see from the plot in the upper right the residuals don't follow a normal distribution.

How can I cure that?

I have tried putting the squares of the variables in the model, but they are non-significant and the problem remains.

Comment: The residuals can't follow a normal distribution, as they are restricted to the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: (1) As Dave writes, the residuals *can't* be normal. (2) Even in OLS, normality of residuals is nice to have, but not necessary at all. (3) Logistic regression in particular makes no normality assumption at all on the residuals. You have a non-problem.

Comment: So I guess there is a bug in that package, as it should not display that plot at all

Comment: @Dave These are likely *deviance residuals,* which are subject to no such restriction.

Comment: raffaem, studying these residuals directly will be revealing.  The following two commands show how to extract them (demonstrating there's no bug, btw) and plot them.  `indf$Residual <- residuals(mod);
qqnorm(indf$Residual, col=ifelse(indf$default=="No", "Gray", "Red"))`

Comment: Residuals can vary within $(-1, 1)$ if observed is $0$ or $1$ and predicted probability is in $(0, 1)$. Those shown are presumably scaled by some standard error.

Comment: @Nick As I wrote earlier, these are deviance residuals.  (I know you are a Stata expert but) the `R` documentation is clear about this (on the help page for `residuals.glm`).  Its references include McCullagh and Nelder (1989) and a couple of contemporary book chapters on GLM residuals.

Comment: The docs were indeed not clear about this, so I added some more details about the plots ([see here](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/check_model.html)). The plots for linearity assumptions (formerly titles as "Heteroscedasticity") and the plot with the overlayed normal curve use "default" residuals (which are deviance residuals for glm's), and the QQ-plot as well as homogeneity plot use standardized Pearson's residuals for glm's (which should be in line with the default result from base R "plot()" on a model object.

Comment: @whuber I saw your comment and naturally agree with it. My allusion (perhaps too gentle) was to the uncorrected first comment by Dave which states that residuals are between $0$ and $1$. Even if residuals are raw residuals,  observed $-$ predicted, that isn't so.

Comment: @whuber The second sentence of my first comment can and perhaps should be deleted as not adding to earlier points. The first sentence still has a little value, although "if" means "if and only if".

Comment: I am wayyy more confused than I should be. Are those _deviance residuals_ required to be normally distributed?

Comment: @raffaem No. There is no such requirement.

Comment: As noted the assumptions of logistic regression and linear regression are not the same. In linear regression (unlike logistic regression) you do need normality to calculate the p value, but with a reasonable number of cases normality does not matter even there. I have found no agreement on what that number has to be, but I think around 100 would be conservative. To quibble slightly with an earlier comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked what the performance package calculates exactly, but these are likely deviance or Pearson residuals. Both behave pretty similar and are based on the idea to scale the residual deviation to the expected variance.

Most GLM distributions (such as Poisson or binomial) will be asymptotically normal with some dependency of the variance on the mean, and in this case, deviance / Pearson residuals will become normal. So, for large counts (Poisson) or a large number of trials (binomial), it makes sense to check those residuals for normality.

Unfortunately, those requirements are rarely met in practice.  In your case, I expect that you have 0/1 data, and in which case this won't work at all.

A possible solution would be to aggregate data points. A far better solution, however, is to calculate randomised quantile residuals, which have proper distributional properties across the entire spectrum of possible outcomes. I recommend using the [DHARMa package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html) (disclaimer: I am the developer). Read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html), which explains how this works, and note that there is a separate section on [0/1 logistic residuals](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#binomial-data).